# Pandas: pd.DateOffset error while adding weeks to date

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying create a column 'planned_off_hire_date' that is basically 'complete_date' plus number of weeks in 'hire_duration' column.

**My df:**

```
     complete_date      hire_duration_wks planned_off_hire_date
      2020-12-27               13.0                   NaT
      2020-12-30               15.0                   NaT
      2020-12-31               16.0                   NaT
      2021-3-1                 17.0                   NaT
      2021-1-18                18.0                   NaT
      2021-1-14                13.0                   NaT
      2021-1-18                14.0                   NaT
```

**My code:**

```
df['hire_duration_wks'] = pd.to_numeric(df['hire_duration_wks'])
df['planned_off_hire_date'] = df['complete_date'] + pd.DateOffset(weeks=(df['hire_duration_wks']))
```

**Error:**

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

**Expected result:**

```
 complete_date      hire_duration_wks planned_off_hire_date
  2020-12-27               13.0             2021-3-28
  2020-12-30               15.0             2021-4-14
  2021-4-10                3.0              2021-5-1
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using this:

```
df['planned_off_hire_date'] = df['complete_date'] + pd.DateOffset(weeks=(df['hire_duration_wks']))
```

Make use of `apply()` method:

```
df['planned_off_hire_date']=df['complete_date'] + df['hire_duration_wks'].apply(lambda x:pd.DateOffset(weeks=x))
```

**Note:** The above method gives you a warning so ignore it as its a warning not an error

Now if you print `df` you will get your desired output:

```
complete_date   hire_duration_wks   planned_off_hire_date
0   2020-12-27      13.0                2021-03-28
1   2020-12-30      15.0                2021-04-14
2   2020-12-31      16.0                2021-04-22
3   2021-03-01      17.0                2021-06-28
4   2021-01-18      18.0                2021-05-24
5   2021-01-14      13.0                2021-04-15
6   2021-01-18      14.0                2021-04-26
```

Comment: Works flawlessly , Thank you very much!

Comment: If you wish, please consider accepting the answer to signal others that the issue is resolved (and also to keep people here motivated in helping others..) **:)**